# Insert \nobreak into subsection title in titletoc's \titlecontents star version

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, titletoc

I want the label and title of subsection typsetting as a paragraph but NEVER break down in a subsection title. Say, the code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents*
{subsection}
{}
{\thecontentslabel:\nobreakspace}{}
{\nobreakspace(\thepage)}[.\quad]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents



\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\subsection{A very long subsection}
\subsection{Again a subsection}
\subsection{A longest subsection in the article!}

\end{document}
```

I want the label of subsection 1.3 and 1.5 start in a new line respectively, like

```
1.1: A subsection (1)   1.2: Another subsection (1)
1.3: A very long subsection (1)   1.4: Again a subsection (1)
1.5: A longest subsection in the article! (1).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the whole label into a box by adding `\mbox` to the label argument of `\titlecontents`. Also, I guess that you want to set the relevant parts of the TOC ragged-right to avoid labels running into the margin.

```
\titlecontents*%
{subsection}%
{\raggedright}%
{\thecontentslabel:\nobreakspace\mbox}{\mbox}%
{\nobreakspace(\thepage)}[.\quad]
```

Comment: Follow-up question [suppress pagebreaks in titletoc's titlecontents* blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56100/suppress-pagebreaks-in-titletocs-titlecontents-blocks) about increasing pagebreak penalty