# suppress pagebreaks in titletoc's titlecontents* blocks

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, titletoc

How do I suppress pagebreaks in the toc "paragraphs" produced by [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)'s `\titlecontents*` command without stopping linebreaks between subsections?

The follwoing suppresses linebreaks within subsection, but doesn't deal with pagebreaks.
`titlesec` does internally use `\nobreak` and `\addpenalty` in the definition of `\ttl@outnoblock`, but I don't know where I would have to add them.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}[3.8em]{\filright\itshape\contentsmargin{2em}}%
  {\thecontentslabel.\nobreakspace\mbox}{\mbox}{,\nobreakspace\thecontentspage}[][ -- ][.]

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{my first chapter}\label{ch:first}
\section{my first section}\label{sec:first}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{11cm}} %for the example
\chapter{my second chapter}
\section{my second section}\label{sec:second}
\subsection{first subsection}
\subsection{second subsection}
\subsection{third subsection}
\subsection{4th subsection}
\subsection{5th subsection}
\subsection{6th subsection}
\subsection{7th subsection}

\end{document}
```

It might in general be better just to increase the penalty than absolutely forbid the pagebreak, but in my particular case forbidding it might be sufficient.

The pagebreak functionalities of `titletoc` should be retained if possible:

> Pages are never broken between entries if the first one is of an
>   higher level than the second one as, for instance, between a section
>   and a subsection. If both of them are of the same level, the break is
>   allowed, and if the first is lower than the second, it is considered a
>   good place for a page break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is completely foolproof, but it seems to work with your example:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[2.3em]
  {}
  {\filbreak\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage\nobreak}

\titlecontents*{subsection}[3.8em]
  {\filright\itshape\contentsmargin{2em}}
  {\thecontentslabel.\nobreakspace\mbox}{\mbox}
  {,\nobreakspace\thecontentspage}[][ -- ][.]
```

With `\filbreak` we roughly say to break unless what comes before the following `\filbreak` can stay in the page.

For the first section after a chapter we mustn't issue the `\filbreak`: here's a sketch, one needs probably to redefine the chapter entries.

```
\newif\iffilchapter
\titlecontents{chapter}[1cm]
  {}
  {\filbreak\global\filchaptertrue\bfseries\contentslabel{1cm}}
  {\hspace*{-1cm}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage\nobreak}

\titlecontents{section}[2.3em]
  {}
  {\iffilchapter\global\filchapterfalse\else\filbreak\fi\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage\nobreak}

\titlecontents*{subsection}[3.8em]
  {\filright\itshape\contentsmargin{2em}}
  {\thecontentslabel.\nobreakspace\mbox}
  {\mbox}
  {,\nobreakspace\thecontentspage}[][ -- ][.]
```

Comment: When I introduce a chapter before this section the pagebreak will occur between chapter and section, which normally `titletoc` forbidds. Can u improve your answer to restore this benefit (see my edited question)?

Comment: `\filbreak` seems to introduce an additional newline, adding `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before each `\filbreak` gets the vertical spacing correct. Is there something less hacked?